# Possible to treat ordinal variables as continuous for fractional design defining relation?

Tags: experiment-design, ordinal-data, fractional-factorial

I am looking at performing a DOE using the Response Surface approach (control and noise modeled together) for a group of 2 Continuous Control, 1 Continuous Noise and 3 Categorical variables.  2 of the Categorical variables are Nominal, and the third is Ordinal.

Ignoring axial points (I do not care about rotatability) and including enough center runs on the 3 Continuous variables to fully cross the Categorical portion of the design at the Continuous Variables' center results in 108 runs without replication, which is very expensive for our purposes.

I understand that Ordinal variables can be treated as Continuous in some cases, and in this case the ordinal variable is ordinal purely because it's 3 pre-selected range means from actual continuous data (for reasons I won't go into, this is unable to be changed, unfortunately)... so let's say I do that in this case, and code its 3 levels to -1, 0, 1.

I've looked into Hybrid designs, Koshal designs and Hoke - Hoke seemed like it could be a starting point too but its k=4 design loses 5 points from a full factorial while adding an interesting face-centered and edge-centered structure underneath... but then adding the remaining 2 Nominal variables in a crossed design on top seems "messy" (is it actually?).  I will have to work out the alias structure for such a design to see what the effects are on the interactions, which are important to us.

Can I instead use the "4 Continuous Variables" I now have (3 true continuous plus 1 "newly continuous") to do a 2<sup>4-1</sup>  ½-fraction prior to adding the fully-crossed 2 Nominal variables?

If I use a defining relation of lets say I=ABCD and generate the fraction on D=ABC I'm at a Resolution IV design, and the 2-factor interactions are aliased with each other, which I don't want but at least that cuts the Continuous portion of the design in half and frees all main effects from the 2-way interactions... so then I would then cross that 2<sup>4-1</sup>  ½-fraction with the 2 Nominal variables.  Is this breaking some fundamental law of DOE that I've forgotten to generate the experiment this way?

Expanding:

Can you treat all variable types equally in regards to creating a ½ or ¼ fraction based on your selected "generating words?"  E.g. if you have 3 Continuous and 3 Nominal variables, can you generate a 2<sup>6-1</sup> ½-fraction design on any defining relation, such as I=ABCDEF for F when F is one of your Categorical variables?  Do you always have to fully cross Categorical variables after performing your design fraction reduction, or can they be included in that fractional design, even using them to base the fraction upon, in some or all cases?

Comment: If you can develop the experimental design, why can you not change the fact that information from an underlying continuous measurement is mostly discarded?  Please explain.